# Prototype Options For Medium Current Application

Tags: prototyping

I'm looking for the best option to develop a medium current (approx 1-2 amps) prototype board.

Should I be using perfboard, Vero/stripboard or etching a custom board? Or are there any other options available?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

1 or 2A is not that much. If you are worried you can solder some moderately thick wire on the parts carrying larger currents.

Answer (score 2):

How complex is your circuit? How much voltage drop can you tolerate
along the current carrying wires?

If the circuit is not complex you can keep the wire length short 
and use perf-board or strip board. 22AWG works well the
Vector T42-1 and K2A pins.

You could also use vectorboard with the copper plane on it.
Remove strips of copper to form traces and planes. A lot
more work to build (especially with a complex circuit).

Answer (score 2):

If there's significant power conversion / switching electronics, you may have to use a "real" (custom etched) PCB to get good ground planes and keep the parasitic inductances down. This can be the case even in the 0.5A-1A range.

There are other applications where you may need to keep voltage drops low, so plan carefully. We had a "smart" battery charger that used charging currents of 1.25A. The voltage drop along our charger cable was only about 0.1V, but we had SMBus (=I2C more or less) signals referenced to the ground return, and with a 0.1V difference between the ground return potential at either end of the cable, it ate into the SMBus voltage level margin, which isn't that much. Voltage drop along the positive power input wasn't a significant issue, but drops along the ground return had a big effect.

Bottom line: it depends. You need to study your system and decide what kind of voltage drops along the supply lines can be problematic. Then design your system around it. (e.g. star grounds rather than daisy chains in some circuits) Measure the drops in the final system to make sure you are doing OK.

Otherwise, what the other answers said.